Restore a Subversion (SVN) repositories from incremental backups made by XP-DEV.com on AWS S3
I have several Subversion (SVN) repositories hosted at https://xp-dev.com/. This worked very well and reliably for more than 15 years but it seems that some of the servers are down now so that I no longer have access to my repositories. I reported the problem to the company and received a response that the owner passed away and that it is unsure whether the company will be closed down or will be continued. Fortunately, I enabled automatic immediate backups of each SVN 'commit' from XP-DEV.com to AWS S3 as described at [1]. However, I do not know how I can re-generate the SVN repositories based on the backups. According to [1], this is described at the sub-website / project "XP-Dev.com Amazon S3 Backup Tools" [2] that is no longer accessible. The backup of each repository consists of a folder with a subfolder for each revision. The name of each folder is equal to the revision number and each subfolder contains one text file that has the revision number as file name and that contains information about the respective revision as well as the changes made in the revision. The first line of each of these files is "SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2". Does anybody know how I can re-generate the SVN repositories based on the backups?
[1] https://xp-dev.com/docs/user-guide/repositories/external-integrations/amazon-s3-backups.html
[2] http://www.xp-dev.com/wiki/57538/Homepage

I found a solution :-)
I found the no-longer-available website "XP-Dev.com Amazon S3 Backup Tools" at the Internet Archive (Wayback Machine):
https://web.archive.org/web/20230528004408/http://www.xp-dev.com/wiki/57538/Homepage
And I found the zip file with the python scripts "xpdev-amazon-s3-tools-2.zip" on my hard disk as I downloaded it many years ago. As these scripts do not work with python3, I installed python2, used the command python downloadrepo.py <amazon aws access key> <amazon aws private key> <bucket name> <repository unique id> to download the backup and this python script also aggregated the single-commit dump files to one overall dump file (for each repository), which I could load into a newly created (empty) SVN repository with gunzip -c my_repo-0-<last revision>.dump.gz | svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo. Let me know if I should send you "xpdev-amazon-s3-tools-2.zip".
